# segmentation fault on running laravel/homestead on windows 10 and surface pro 3

Tags: segmentation-fault, vagrant, windows-10, homestead

I have a problem setting up laravel/homestead
I got it installed

- windows 10
- Virtualbox 5.0.4
- vagrant 1.7.4

But I get an error

```
$ Vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider ...
==> Default: Importing base box 'laravel / homestead' ...
==> Default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking ...
==> Default: Setting the name of the VM: homestead
==> Default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces ...
==> Default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration ...    
default: Adapter 1: nat    
default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> Default: Forwarding ports ...    
default: 80 => 8000 (adapter 1)
default: 443 => 44300 (adapter 1)    
default: 3306 => 33060 (adapter 1)    
default: 5432 => 54320 (adapter 1)    
default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> Default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations ...
==> Default: Booting VM ...
==> Default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes ...
**Segmentation fault**
```

I can command

```
$ vagrand ssh
```

Or

```
$ ssh vagrand@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
```

Connect to the server

In addition, since the next step will not be setup folders on server and is not Mount code folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue yesterday when i upgraded homestead from 0.2 to 0.3.3, alongside installing the latest vagrant version 1.7.4

**to solve the problem, do the following:**

1. uninstall **vagrant 1.7.4** and **Virtualbox 5.0.4**
2. restart the computer
3. install **vagrant 1.7.2** and **Virtualbox 4.3**
4. restart the computer
5. add this `C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gnuwin32\bin` to your **PATH environment** variable. Make sure it is separated from any other paths by a `;`
6. `cd` (Change Directory ) to Homestead folder and do `vagrant up`